# A script im robot with xmpppy of python, how to detect network failure?

Tags: python, xmpp, bots, xmpppy

I am using xmpppy libary to write a XMPP IM robot.

I want to act on disconnects, but I don't know how to detect disconnects. This could happen if your Jabber server crashes or if you have lost your internet connection.

I found the callback, `RegisterDisconnectHandler(self, DisconnectHandler)`, but it didn't work for the network failure, it only works when I explicitly call the method "disconnect".

How do I detect a network failure or server crash?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try waiting 30 *minutes* after the network failure?  Depending on your network stack's settings, it could take this long to detect.  However, if you're not periodically sending on the socket, you may *never* detect the outage.  This is why many XMPP stacks periodically send a single space character, using an algorithm like:

1. Set timer to `N` seconds
2. On sending a stanza, reset the timer to `N`
3. When the timer fires, send a space.

Comment: Could Please give some detials about how to send such a stanza?

Comment: The space character isn't a stanza. You should just be able to do `send(" ")`.